# Windows 10 won't synchronise keyboard

Tags: windows, clipboard

I have Swiftkey running on a Pixel 6 pro phone running Android 12. Swiftkey has a feature whereby it will synchronise the clipboard contents, through the cloud, to the clipboard on Windows 10. This sometimes works, but I would prefer it to work reliably.

What usually happens is that the phone displays a message asking me to `"finish setting this up on your Windows device"` — which I of course have done many times in settings:

But nothing changes as a result. Does anyone know how to get this working reliably? I know that it can work, because sometimes it does.

[image: screenshot of setting window]

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Swiftkey rather than Windows.

Comment: It's a problem with the Microsoft sync service, I think. I am just surprised that so useful a feature isn't more widely used, so other people would have had my problem :-)